# I need help adding an image behind my page links in my header

Tags: css, web, squarespace

Lets start with I'm using square space CSS code injector. I am trying to have some images placed behind the text links that read (menu, what we sellin', wholesale) With my background image it is hard to see the links. I would like to add small wooden boards as the image behind them. Appreciate any help .

My website: www.slurpnsnack.com [My website](https://www.slurpnsnack.com)

edit: I do not want to add a background image to the header itself. I am wondering if there is a way to attach the picture itself to behind the link, or just how to go about placing my own links there.

Answer (score 0):

Your links are held in a div with class `.header-nav-item`

So CSS along these lines:

```
.header-nav-item {
  color: white;
  background-image: url(wood.jpg);
}
```

should be enough, though you may want to play around with background positioning and sizing depending on how consistent you want the look to be on the various sized items and what your image is actually like.

Comment: That did not seem to work although no image shows up. I did place my image in the "()" I am quite new to coding as well.  thanks for the help

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to look at the divs holding the a elements and see what formating they have. When I went to your site and set the above it worked fine.